# How to remove a row in excel without affecting a formula based on integer values?

Tags: excel

I have a use-case with a formula based on integers. It basically takes one value and subtracts an unknown range of numbers from it. 
The range of numbers to subtract change every day, but do not exceed 999. 
Hence, the formula that I have used looks like this: =B1-(SUM(C1:C999))

Now my problem is, that I need to be able to delete cells in column C without affecting the formula. 
I have tried locking the cells like this: =B1-(SUM($C$1:$C$999)), but the formula still changes when I delete cells.

INDIRECT won't work either, cause I'm not working with text strings. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you not use `=B1-SUM(C:C)`, but noting that this won't work if you have "anything else" in your C column after row 999?

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use @RichardHansell suggestion, because you may have data below c999:

```
=B1-SUM(C:C)
```

you could use one of these:

```
=B1-SUM(INDIRECT("c1:c999"))

=B1-SUM(OFFSET($C$1,0,0,999))
```

Those are both volatile functions so will recalculated when anything changes. For a non-volatile function:

```
=$B$1-SUM(INDEX($C:$C,1,1):INDEX($C:$C,999,1))
```